# Jenkins git plugin does not allow parameter on repository URL

Tags: git, jenkins

First of all, I can access my git repository with my user credentials.

But if I create a string parameter with name of my repository and use this parameter on repository url ( ${parameter} with value ssh://git@myrepo/java/login.git), during the build process git plugin prints the expanded value on console log but I receive a authentication error. Or git plugin tries to connect to url without expand parameter or it forget to send user credentials.

```
Cloning repository ssh://git@myrepo/java/login.git
git init /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/teste/workspace
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@myrepo/java/login.git
git --version
git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@myrepo/java/login.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=1
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@myrepo/java/login.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=1" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1325)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$200(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:257)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:413)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:846)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:879)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1252)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is it possible to use parameters to define git repository?

Answer (score 0):

omit the 'ssh://' in your parameter and it should work perfectly well.